# Does aqueous component contribute to the equilibrium constant?

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, phase, reference-request

Consider an equilibrium reaction with an aqueous solution $\ce{A(aq)}$ in equilibrium phase with gas:
$$\ce{A(aq) + B(g) <=>[$K_\mathrm{eq}$] C(g)}$$
Would the equilibrium constant have aqueous solution $\ce{A(aq)}$ contributing to it?

In my opinion I think it would. Can anyone please correct me? Also, please help me  find literature which explains equilibrium constant in details.

Comment: When a substance is distributed between two phases chemists define a partition coefficient.

Answer (score 2):

- If you are talking about a species dissolved in a aqueous solution then yes it would feature in the constant .
- However if you are referring to the solvent itself then no it wouldn't feature in the constant this is because the concentration of the solvent is constant , as well as the fact that it is present on both sides of the equation since both reactants and products are dissolved in the same solvent
- If you are referring to a partial pressure equillibrium constant , then a hybrid one will have to be created that has the partial pressure of the gases and the concentration of species that are not gases
- Using a Kc value would mean simply taking the concentration of both the gases and the solutes , to end up with a constant , however solvents are excluded because the concentration of solvents is constant and is thereby thought as being absorbed in the eq constant itself
- Derivation of the equilibrium constant requires probability and is quite lengthy so maybe you can check the video on khan academy that discusses the derivation

Comment: I am referring to the solute and it is the concentration equilibrium constant,so It is factored in.If it is partial pressure equillibrium constant ,How would you state the pressure of the solute ?

Comment: As I stated before it would be a hybrid constant , one that takes in the partial pressure of gases and the concentration of the solute , so you don't take the pressure or the solute but the concentration of it